# Exact Sequence Equivalence

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the exact sequences

$$0 \to A \xrightarrow{i} B \xrightarrow{\alpha} C \xrightarrow{r} D \to 0$$

and

$$0 \to A \xrightarrow{i'} B' \xrightarrow{\alpha'} C \xrightarrow{r'} D \to 0$$

Does it follow that $i = i'$, $B=B'$, $\alpha = \alpha'$, or $r=r'$?

I think that none of the equivalences have to follow. Is that correct?

My reasoning is that the images of $r$ and $r'$ are equal because they are equal to $D$. But the kernels of $r$ and $r'$ are not necessarily equal. Then the images of $\alpha$ and $\alpha'$ are not necessarily equivalent. Then $B$ and $B'$ are not necessarily equivalent.

However, I am failing to think of a counterexample, which makes makes me unsure of my reasoning.

Comment: This might depend on the category you are working in. In the category of finite dimensional vector spaces, you will have $B \cong B'$: Being an exact sequence implies the alternating sum of the dimensions is zero. Hence $\dim B = \dim B'$, and therefor $B \cong B'$.

Comment: @red_trumpet Thank you! For now I'm reading about sequences of homology groups, but I will think more about the dimensions and what that tells me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take $C=\mathbb Z/8\oplus\mathbb Z/2$ and $D=\mathbb Z/4$. If $p:\mathbb Z/8\to\mathbb Z/4$ and $q:\mathbb Z/2\to\mathbb Z/4$ are the natural surjection and injection respectively, then you can take $r=(p,0)$, with kernel $(\mathbb Z/2)^2$, and $r’=(p,q)$, with kernel $\mathbb Z/4$. You can now choose the remaining part of the sequences.

Comment: Thank you! now I see what kinds of examples are simplest when I have these types of questions.